# 3.5 inch TFT Display and RC522 use on rasp 3b+

Tags: pi-3b+

I am new to raspberry. Currently, I am trying applying `3.5 inch TFT` Display and `rc522` on my `rasp 3b+`. Is that possible ?

I already used `pin 1 to 26 for tft display`. Then what can i do if i trying to use rc522 ?

Comment: yes it is possible, read/write your datas with the RC522 and display informations on your TFT display.

Comment: Thank you Ephemeral. 
I already used pin 1 to 26 for tft display. 
Then what can i do if i trying to use rc522?

Comment: This type of [project](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-attendance-system/) works because the LCD screen is not directly put on the output of the GPIO pins of the raspberry...Maybe you can implement SPI bit-banging with the GPIO pins 29 to 40 ?

Comment: Thank you for the link..is that possible i move the rc522 pin to another gpio?

Comment: Maybe you can implement SPI bit-banging with the GPIO pins 29 to 40...
but the remaining GPIO pins must be able to generate a clock and I cannot answer you.

Comment: ok.i try first..i will update here if found that way.thank you